# How to change individual markers when plotting with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I have the code below and am trying to figure out how to shape of markers in a matplotlib array. Specifically, the first marker point in the array should be a circle, and the second marker point in the array should be a square.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.title('Map')

plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

RedLineNames = np.array(["Tub Gallery","Maul Gallery","Rocket Gallery","ClasseArt Gallery ","Wiseworlds Gallery"])
RedLineCoords = np.array([[3950, 4250],[1350,450],[3550, 3200],[2500, 2500],[400, 2750]])

# Set marker points
plt.plot(RedLineCoords[:,0],RedLineCoords[:,1],marker='^',markersize=10,color='red')

# Draw connecting red line
plt.plot(RedLineCoords[:,0],RedLineCoords[:,1], 'r-')

# Add plot names
for i in range(len(RedLineCoords)):
    plt.text(RedLineCoords[i,0],RedLineCoords[i,1]+20,RedLineNames[i])
    
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Set the markers with a separate plot call

  - [matplotlib: markers](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html)
- See the **Notes** section near the bottom of [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) for the marker and color format strings.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

RedLineNames = np.array(["Tub Gallery","Maul Gallery","Rocket Gallery","ClasseArt Gallery ","Wiseworlds Gallery"])
RLC = np.array([[3950, 4250], [1350,450], [3550, 3200], [2500, 2500], [400, 2750]])

# create the figure and axes; use the object oriented approach
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))

# draw the line plot
ax.plot(RLC[:,0], RLC[:,1], color='red')

# set the first two markers separately (black circle and blue square)
ax.plot(RLC[0, 0], RLC[0, 1], 'ok', RLC[1, 0], RLC[1, 1], 'sb')

# set the rest of the markers (green triangle)
ax.plot(RLC[2:, 0], RLC[2:, 1], '^g')

# Add plot names
for i in range(len(RLC)):
    ax.text(RLC[i,0], RLC[i,1]+20, RedLineNames[i])
    
ax.set_title('Map')

ax.invert_yaxis()
    
plt.show()
```

[image]